# Capistrano task not released console after execution of cli commend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line-interface, rake, capistrano

Rails 7.

Ruby 3.1.0

App has Capistrano for deployment in deployment we have many rake taks when we run individual task all run fine but when I so full run with cap deploy after few task it get stuck at one tak which has cli command execution it executed that command but after that it get stuck it not release console and not morning further.. I tried with many different cli tools but still, it got stuck at the same place.

this my CLI command

```
cmd = "RAILS_ROOT=/home/ubuntu/www/xxx/releases/20240112174418 RAILS_ENV=production god -c config/deploy"

i try task run by many cli ways but all geeting stuck 
system("#{cmd} /t")
IO.popen("#{cmd} /t") {|f| puts f.gets }
`{`#{cmd} /t`}`
```

if I run that rake task separately it works but when I run with Capistrano deploy it gets stuck.

Comment: I think I have the exact same issue. It worked fine until I upgraded to Ruby 3. May I ask what version of capistrano you're using? I'm on ruby 3.1.2 and capistrano 3.16. Thanks.